# How to use distinguish differenct object type in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio, typescript-typings, type-systems

How to distinguish different object type in TypeScript?

```
interface CC {
    a: number;
    b: string
}

interface B {
    c:number
}



const obj:  CC |  B = {
    a: 1,
    c: 1
} 
// valid
```

I want the obj only valid when

```
{
  a:number,
  b:string
}
```

or

```
{
  c:number
}
```

not what union type or intersection type behave.

Answer (score 0):

One way to force typescript to pick either `B` or `CC` is to set a common variable with a specific value.

[Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwjUF4oG8BQUNVJAXFAjANzqYCGeAdgK4C2ARhAE7GZR14DOwjAlhQOaoAvsVTZoAIUQoSGcXgBMLTAGNKtBo2GiVAewpcouugCs8cKAB8oUpGlbyCAGllRyz12oLagA) :

```
type CC = {
    type: 1;
    a: number;
    b: string
};

type B = {
    type: 2;
    c: number
};

const obj: CC | B = {
    type: 1,
    a: 1,
    c: 1
};
```

[image]